# Ionic back button after modal

Tags: ionic-framework, navbar

Upon pushing a product to the cart I have a popup modal to ask user about whether he wants to continue shopping, or go to checkout:

```
var confirmPopup = $ionicPopup.confirm({
                    title: 'End',
                    template: 'Anything else?',
                    buttons: [{
                        text: 'Yes',
                        type: 'button-positive',
                        onTap: function (e) {
                            $window.location.href = '#/category';
                            window.location.reload();
                        }
                    }, {
                        text: 'No',
                        type: 'button-default',
                        onTap: function (e) {
                            $window.location.href = '#/cart';
                            window.location.reload();
                        }
                    }]
                });
```

The problem is that even though I have `index.html` defined as so:

```
<div>
    <ion-nav-bar class="bar-dark">
        <ion-nav-back-button class="button-icon icon ion-ios-arrow-back">Back</ion-nav-back-button>
    </ion-nav-bar>

    <ion-nav-view></ion-nav-view>
</div>
```

When I get redirected from modal, there is no back button. I tried to hard-code it in the `cart.html`, but no luck. Is there a way to do it?

Comment: r u not aware of ui routing ?

Comment: What do you mean? I know that Ionic uses ui-routing, but I am mostly doing my work in Laravel, so this is kind of cross jumping to other platform, so my methods may not be the best :)

Comment: why not try $state.go('');

Comment: Once I answered...I found it. $state.go() does it. Thanks